# Laravel - how to delete polymorphic relations of model with belongsTo relation?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables. Two of them are *monomorphic* and two of them are *polymorphic*.

**Monomorphic:**
Templates, Modules

**Polymorphic:**
Documents, Images

Now, `templates` and `modules` have both `documents` and `images` and each `Template` has many `Module`s and `modules` have foreign key that is set to cascade on deletion of `templates`.

Now, if I delete a `Template` the associated `Module`s will be deleted but the associated polymorphic relations of `Module` will stay in Database. I haven't tried anything because I am completely clueless.

Anything I could do to automatically delete associations of `Module` when `Template` is deleted? I think the deletion here in this is being handled by Database itself and Eloquent doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: I would simply add a line in destroy method to delete whatever you want to delete

Comment: @lewis4u What you're suggesting is: First check related Modules then for each module check documents and images and delete them one by one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it is a polymorphic relationship, the cascading delete cannot be handled by a foreign key.

If you still want the deletes to be handled at the database level, you will need to write some type of database trigger functionality.

There are also a couple options if you want to handle this at the application level.

One option is to update your code so that everywhere you delete your `Template`, you also make sure to delete all of it's polymorphic relations.

Another option would be to create an event handler for the `deleting` event. The `deleting` event is fired by Eloquent whenever you delete an Eloquent model. Inside this deleting event, you can access the polymorphic relationship and delete them, as well.

If the `deleting` event method sounds okay, there is a package that implements all of this for you, and makes it very easy to setup for your models: [`shiftonelabs/laravel-cascade-deletes`](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-cascade-deletes). Full disclosure: I wrote the package.

With this package, you just add the `CascadesDeletes` trait to your `Template` model, and then add a `$cascadeDeletes` property that contains an array of all the relationships to delete when a `Template` instance is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It's not fully automatic, but I handle it very easy with the `destroy()` Eloquent method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-an-existing-model-by-key In addition, when you will use it with [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#introduction), it works like a charm...

Example:

```
$template = Template::find(1);

Module::destroy($template->modules);

$template->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use delete method on both types of relationship:

```
$template = Template::find(1);

$template->modules()->delete();
$template->images()->delete();

$template->delete();
```

Key note here is that `$template->modules` returns a collection instance while `$template->modules()` return an eloquent relationship where you can chain delete() method.